# Event argument for click function [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, events, arguments

I don't know right way to pass event argument for click function.

So I can't pass that course:

> http://www.codecademy.com/courses/you-and-jquery/0?curriculum_id=4fc3018f74258b0003001f0f#!/exercises/4

Who can help me?

**UPDATE:**

My answer is like below, but it still doesn't right.

```
function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
    $bar.click(
        function(e) {
            alert(value);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event argument is passed in the click function as follows

```
$(element).click(function(event){ // <-- see event argument getting passed in
     // now you can use event object here
});
```

**EDIT**

This is how the code started

```
function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
    // add a click event to the bar that 
    // pops up an alert with the bars value
    $bar.click(
        // your code goes here!
    );
}
```

This is how my code looks like inside the function

```
function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
    // add a click event to the bar that 
    // pops up an alert with the bars value
    $bar.click(
        function(e){alert(value);}
    );
}
```

Though I just tested and it works fine the other ways too.  Try resetting and typing it over

Comment: I have updated my question. But I can't pass the course.

Comment: worked fine here http://www.codecademy.com/courses/you-and-jquery/0?curriculum_id=4fc3018f74258b0003001f0f#!/exercises/4

Comment: I'm guessing you have to write everything on one line?  not sure how that application works.. but that's what I did and it worked fine

Comment: my code in my question. when I press Run button, still fail: "Make sure to define the argument to .click as an anonymous function that displays the alert."

Comment: @LucyFord I just tested and it works fine the other ways too.  Try resetting and typing it over.  Thats how I got it to work the first time

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have to write on one line. thanks!